# Load bitmap lazy, just before it is seen

Tags: android, android-listview, lazy-loading, android-bitmap

I've a Listview with images. I am using an adapter to display the images because i get just a URL from a web service. At the moment i load all images Async, that works but its very inefficient. I get 100-200 images / URLs and mostly i do not need all.
I am looking for a solution to load a bitmap just before it is seen.
for example:

```
Bitmap 1 (i see it on the screen -> load bitmap)
Bitmap 2 (i see it on the screen -> load bitmap)
Bitmap 3 (i don't see it on the screen but its the next one -> load bitmap)
Bitmap 4 (i don't see it, nothing to do)
Bitmap 5 (i don't see it, nothing to do)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: my guess is that your webservice is returning all 200 at once? 
Consider changing your webservice to return one at a time, or a small set of images. Then just request the ones you need. ListView is able to connect to the webservice and request images singularly as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the Holder pattern for your `listview`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use Universal Image Loader library, and lazy loading works perfect, take a look at it here:

[Universal Image Loader at Github](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)